Hazelcast data sync with cloud foundary pools
I have one application running in two cloud foundary servers. I have hazelcast in-memory caching enabled for these two pools. The nodes are not in sync so one node has updated data but the other has stale data and needs a restart everytime to be updated. I was reading that using multicast we can make it work and put the both servers data in sync.
`hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: true
        multicast-group: 224.2.2.3
        multicast-port: 54327
        multicast-time-to-live: 32
        multicast-timeout-seconds: 2
        trusted-interfaces:
          - 192.168.1.102`

I am not sure if I put this config and whitelist my IPs from both the pools. So in that case will the nodes be in sync and have the same data ?

You have two different options

Use Hazelcast Enterprise Edition and configure Wan Replication. With this option, you will have two different clusters in different data centers and Wan Replication will sync data between source and target
Use Hazelcast Open Source and use one of the discovery mechanisms provided by Hazelcast to create a single cluster. There are many supported mechanisms such as Multicast, TCP list etc. After the cluster members discover each other, the data will be distributed on members. You can configure the number of backups for your data. This way when a member shuts down, the back up on another member will take over

